# error: expected expression before '=' token in the line starting with 'rad'

Tags: expression, message, token

/*input section*/

```
printf("Enter the value for a: ");
scanf("%d", &a);

printf("Enter the value for b: ");
scanf("%d", &b);

printf("Enter the value for theta: ");
scanf("%d", &theta);
```

/*computation section*/

```
rad = (theta * ( PI/180 ));
c = sqrt( pow(a,2) + pow(b,2) - (2 * a * b * cos(rad)));
per = (a + b + c);
area = (a * b * sin(rad)/2);
```

/*output section*/

```
printf("The perimeter equals: %f\n", per);
printf("The area equals: %f\n", area);
```

how do I fix this error message?

Comment: What language? Are you sure that `rad` is not a keyword?